# How to get a variable inside a Try-Catch block and inside asynchronous method

Tags: java

I want to know why the method myServer() return null,  and not the value "result" that is assigned to finalResult  inside " public void onSuccessInMainThread(...)" I'm new to java and there are some things I don't understand

```
protected LemmaValidationJob finalResult;

public LemmaValidationJob myServer(){   
    TaskConfiguration config = new TaskConfiguration(TaskType.RELATION);
    config.setLanguage(Language.EN);

    try{
        AnnotationManager.getInstance().getData(config,
            new MainThreadCallback<LemmaValidationJob>(){

                @Override
               public void onSuccessInMainThread(LemmaValidationJob result){    
                   finalResult = result;
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailureInMainThread(Throwable cause){
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               }
           });
    } catch (AuthenticationRequiredException e) {
        System.err.println("NO LOGIN");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

Comment: The reasons that would make it null could eitehr be the method onSuccessInMainThread is not getting called. Or the LemmaValidationJob result parameter is null. Have you tried putting in a breakpoint when debugging on the line finalResult = result to see if the method is getting called and if the result parameter has any value?

Comment: yes, the variable result give me a value, but that value is dosen't take it from finalResult.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `myServer()` method probably returns before the execution of the `onSuccessInMainThread()` method.

If a method performs an ansychronous thread then in most cases the calling method must also have an asynchronous signature. So in this case `myServer` must be `void`, and must receive a callback as a parameter. So it will be something like

```
public void myServer(Consumer<LemmaValidationJob> onSuccess){   
    TaskConfiguration config = new TaskConfiguration(TaskType.RELATION);
    config.setLanguage(Language.EN);

    try{
        AnnotationManager.getInstance().getData(config,
            new MainThreadCallback<LemmaValidationJob>(){

                @Override
               public void onSuccessInMainThread(LemmaValidationJob result){    
                   onSuccess.apply(result);
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailureInMainThread(Throwable cause){
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               }
           });
    } catch (AuthenticationRequiredException e) {
        System.err.println("NO LOGIN");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```